# Draw polyline using Mapbox from Latitude and longitude Arrays - Swift 3 iOS

Tags: ios, swift3, mapbox

I have two arrays for latitude and longitude and i need to draw a polyline from the values in these two arays. I am able to draw polygon from preset values using this code:

```
 var points = [
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.729437724412420, longitude: -74.00527954101562),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.718249486603604, longitude: -74.00725364685059),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.720656417464404, longitude: -74.00545120239258),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.718379593199494, longitude: -74.00519371032715),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.717273679029205, longitude: -74.00639533996582),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.713435363794270, longitude: -73.99841308593750),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.714150998671556, longitude: -73.99755477905273),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.716037635568070, longitude: -73.99643898010254),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.728201906826750, longitude: -73.99137496948242),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.743810548166270, longitude: -73.97961616516113),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.746671735171680, longitude: -73.98613929748535),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.735941649217736, longitude: -73.99377822875977),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.738673108048920, longitude: -73.99970054626465),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.729437724412420, longitude: -74.00527954101562)
    ]

        let polygon = MGLPolygon(coordinates: &points, count: UInt(points.count))
        map.add(polygon)
```

But not able to **draw a polyline**.

Comment: I have checked its working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with below codes

```
   mapVw.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    mapVw.setCenter(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.729437724412420, longitude: -74.00527954101562), zoomLevel: 11, animated: false)
    mapVw.delegate = self




    var coordinates = [
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.729437724412420, longitude: -74.00527954101562),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.718249486603604, longitude: -74.00725364685059),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.720656417464404, longitude: -74.00545120239258),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.718379593199494, longitude: -74.00519371032715),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.717273679029205, longitude: -74.00639533996582),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.713435363794270, longitude: -73.99841308593750),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.714150998671556, longitude: -73.99755477905273),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.716037635568070, longitude: -73.99643898010254),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.728201906826750, longitude: -73.99137496948242),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.743810548166270, longitude: -73.97961616516113),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.746671735171680, longitude: -73.98613929748535),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.735941649217736, longitude: -73.99377822875977),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.738673108048920, longitude: -73.99970054626465),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.729437724412420, longitude: -74.00527954101562)
    ]

    let shape = MGLPolygon(coordinates: &coordinates, count: UInt(coordinates.count))

    mapVw.add(shape)


func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, alphaForShapeAnnotation annotation: MGLShape) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.5
}
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, strokeColorForShapeAnnotation annotation: MGLShape) -> UIColor {
    return .red
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, fillColorForPolygonAnnotation annotation: MGLPolygon) -> UIColor {
    return .yellow
}
```

Its perfect

Comment: Actually i need to draw a polyline not a polygon exactly,  from two different arrays, ie latitudeArray and longitude Array

Comment: This is close! You just need to swap out `MGLPolygon` for `MGLPolyline`, then change the styling methods accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to create a polyline annotation, you can do so with this code:

```
    var points = [
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.729437724412420, longitude: -74.00527954101562),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.718249486603604, longitude: -74.00725364685059),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.720656417464404, longitude: -74.00545120239258),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.718379593199494, longitude: -74.00519371032715),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.717273679029205, longitude: -74.00639533996582),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.713435363794270, longitude: -73.99841308593750),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.714150998671556, longitude: -73.99755477905273),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.716037635568070, longitude: -73.99643898010254),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.728201906826750, longitude: -73.99137496948242),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.743810548166270, longitude: -73.97961616516113),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.746671735171680, longitude: -73.98613929748535),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.735941649217736, longitude: -73.99377822875977),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.738673108048920, longitude: -73.99970054626465),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.729437724412420, longitude: -74.00527954101562)
    ]
    let line = MGLPolyline(coordinates: &points, count: UInt(points.count))
    mapView.addAnnotation(line)
```

If you would like to create a polyline style layer, you can do so with this code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didFinishLoading style: MGLStyle) {
    var points = [
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.729437724412420, longitude: -74.00527954101562),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.718249486603604, longitude: -74.00725364685059),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.720656417464404, longitude: -74.00545120239258),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.718379593199494, longitude: -74.00519371032715),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.717273679029205, longitude: -74.00639533996582),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.713435363794270, longitude: -73.99841308593750),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.714150998671556, longitude: -73.99755477905273),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.716037635568070, longitude: -73.99643898010254),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.728201906826750, longitude: -73.99137496948242),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.743810548166270, longitude: -73.97961616516113),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.746671735171680, longitude: -73.98613929748535),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.735941649217736, longitude: -73.99377822875977),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.738673108048920, longitude: -73.99970054626465),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.729437724412420, longitude: -74.00527954101562)
    ]
    let line = MGLPolylineFeature(coordinates: &points, count: UInt(points.count))
    let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "line", shape: line, options: nil)
    style.addSource(source)
    let layer = MGLLineStyleLayer(identifier: "line-layer", source: source)
    style.addLayer(layer)
}
```